# How to append int64 value to biginterger value

Tags: vb.net, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have BigInterger

```
Dim posBigInt As BigInteger = &H27677495
```

Also i have in64

```
Dim int_four As Int64 = &H30034003
```

I want to append int64 value to big integer value it should be:

```
posBigInt = &H2767749530034003
```

how can I accomplish that?

Comment: Can you explain why EXACTLY you want to do this? I have provided an answer but using string concatenation for this type of thing feels dirty. Bit-wise operations might be more appropriate but we'd have to know the specifics of the situation to be sure.

Comment: @jmcilhinney thanks for your help, simply saying, the posBigInt value - &H27677495 is not static, it can be any 4 bytes. So after i get this 4 bytes i need to this 4 bytes ( in our case it is &H27677495) append &H30034003 and XOR it with &H5003600370038003

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit dodgy but you could do this:

```
posBigInt = BigInteger.Parse(posBigInt.ToString("X8") & int_four.ToString("X8"),
                             NumberStyles.HexNumber)
```

That's converting both numbers to 8-digit hexadecimal text first, concatenating them and then parsing the result.